# Application.EnableEvents = False not working

Tags: excel, vba, programming-languages

I don't seem to understand the strange behaviour of Excel 2007, and after a dozen solutions, I came to you asking for help.

I have office 2007.

Here is my class module code :

```
Public WithEvents App As Application
Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  MsgBox "event din app"
End Sub
```

Here is my InitializeAppObject module :

```
Dim X As New EventClassModule
Sub InitializeApp()
    Set X.App = Application

    MsgBox "am facut setarea"

End Sub
```

Here is my Sheet one code :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("a1:c10")) Is Nothing _
    Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        MsgBox "suntem in range"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        MsgBox "nu suntem in range"
    End If
End Sub
```

Before changing any values on the grid, I execute the InitializeApp() procedure.

From my understanding, the sheet event should be triggered first, then the workbook one, and then the application one. However this is not the case. It first fires up the workbook one, the the application one, and finally the sheet one.

1. Is Excel malfunctioning or I got it wrong ?
2. How can I execute just the sheet event? cause obviously the Application.EnableEvents = false is not doing any good from stopping the event from being triggered upstream.

Thank you so much in advance for all your help!

kind regards,
radu

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem may be that you're using the SelectionChange event in the sheet module.  You're correct about the order of events.  Here's how it goes - you're events have a *

```
Worksheet_Change
Workbook_SheetChange*
Application_SheetChange*
```

then assuming the selection moves after you enter something

```
Worksheet_SelectionChange*
Workbook_SheetSelectionChange
Application_SheetSelectionChange
```

Nothing in your code is triggering events, so putting message boxes in between EnableEvents doesn't achieve the desired result.  All of the events are already queued up by the time the first event code runs.  If instead, you had

```
Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sh.Range("a1").Value = 1
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Then the code that changed the value of A1 would not trigger any events.  If you only want to run the Worksheet_Change event, you should delete the other event code.  OK, it's probably there for a good reason.  But whatever the logic is for when you run which event code needs to be in the procedure.  For instance, if you only want to run the Worksheet_Change event on a particular worksheet name "Master", you would set it up like this

```
Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name <> "Master" Then
        MsgBox "event din app"
    End If
End Sub
```

And the Worksheet_Change event code would be in master sheet's class module, so it would only respond to events on that page.

Comment: thank you very much for your time. however your answer was very ambigus, in my opinion. I shall turn over to a book and come back later.